# Music stop/start onclick code works only on the first time, then plays additional tracks in parallel

Tags: android, button

I'm creating a simple app that plays and stops music on button click. For the first time, when I click start music button, the music plays and stops when clicking it again. The problem is that when I click it again, it starts playing and doesn't stop on the next click anymore. Instead, it plays same music again in parallel (e.g. however many times I click, that many tracks are played in parallel).

The code for the button XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="#7FFF00"
        android:text="Start Music"
        android:onClick="music" />
```

and MainActivity.java

```
public void music(View v)
{
    Button bu= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    String ans=bu.getText().toString();
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my);  
    switch(ans)
    {
        case "Stop Music":
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.stop();
            bu.setText("Start Music");
            break;

        case "Start Music":     
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
            bu.setText("Stop Music");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `MediaPlayer` instance on every button click. Just create it once in your activity's `onCreate()` and refer to that single instance in your `music()` method.

Remember to call `mp.release()` as well, when you exit your activity.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above Image shows various states of MediaPlayer. The Key thing you need to notice here is that After the Starting the music (Start State) when you stop the music it goes to Prepared State. Now if You want to play your song again, You need to prepare() it first.

Hence before playing the music:

```
mp.reset();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Hence When you hit the play button after the stop button! It will `prepare()` then `play()`. `reset()` is simply resetting the song to start from beginning.